# No module names 'Keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am absolutely new to the development of deep learning and currently, I am just preparing my system to start with some basic tutorials.

I followed the Tutorial on [this Blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-environment-setup-for-deep-learning-on-windows-10-c373786e36d1) to prepare the environment for the development of deep leaning projects.

I was successful to do the steps mentioned in the tutorial expect the last one. I Installed `tensorflow-gpu` using the command `pip install tensorflow-gpu` in the Python 3.7 Anaconda.

[image]

**PROBLEM:** As per the tutorial, I should try to execute the following commands to check if everything went OK with the installation:

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> import keras
```

The first command was exectued without any issue but the second command (i.e. `import keras`) is throwing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'keras'
```

Comment: Try to install keras with `pip install keras`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You installed tensorflow, thats why you can import keras from tensorflow

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Or you install keras separately with:

```
pip install keras
```

and then import it with:

```
import keras
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import **keras** by pip (command for use).

**pip install keras**

After completion of above command you can check whether Keras install or not in your system by

**pip list | grep -i keras**

Output on console

**DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.**

**Keras (2.2.4)**

**Keras-Applications (1.0.7)**

**Keras-Preprocessing (1.0.9)**